# android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED Not getting triggered

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have this receiver declared in my Manifest file. I am receiving the broadcast in one phone that is Samsung Note 2 Jelly bean but not receiving the broadcast on another phone, Redmi 4.4.4. Please let me know what might be the issue.

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".UpgradeReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <data android:scheme="package" />               
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```